# Event Sourcing Architecture: Ingesting event data from Phones

Tags: event-sourcing

We will be streaming data from Phones (<= 5000) to a server. We were previously sending the data using MQTT to AWS IOT. Now we want to run this locally. Estimated size per second to be ingested is 5000 phone * 500 bytes = 2.5 MB to 5 MB. 5 mBps = 5*8 mbps i.e. we are looking at something like 20 to 40 mbps. This is not a bottleneck however the number of independent source instances is.

So, I was trying to scale down the problem and use something light, which can stream at 1 or 2 msgs per second from 5000 devices. I tested websockets but one socket is only able to read asynchronously from 200 end clients. Is it better to code this up or use something Eclipse MQTT or Websockets to Elastic Search or Kafka. We had a grpc instance before that was sending a larger packet so it was draining the phone battery faster as the structure was a json.

Why I want to use a simple system so that it becomes easy to maintain for the end client when the software is deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get that right, but if the phone is sending something every second, that will drain the battery no matter what technology you use. Phones are supposed to be in standby for multiple minutes, and should communicate only through a central push service to make waking as streamlined and as rare as possible. That being said, here are some pointers:

I wouldn't pick MQTT, there are multiple problems with it. If you are using QoS 0, you have no backpressure mechanism, server can be overwhelmed. If you are using QoS 1, you sort-of can have backpressure, but it will highly depend on the implementation, some might timeout after a while. Also, QoS 1 will be persistent on most implementations, so you'll have an iops bottleneck, which will most likely not handle 1000s of iops / second. QoS 2 is even worse.

ElasticSearch is a persistence technology, not a messaging one. You can use it to store stuff, but it will not help you with the communication of data.

Kafka is a messaging technology, and sort-of a persistence one as well. It can easily deal with the amount of messages you have on a single node. However, you can't have that natively from the phones themselves, you would still need some communication medium for that.

For the communication I would pick something extremely simple. gRPC would work. Or just plain TCP/IP with Netty. Or even UDP if you don't care about message delivery guarantees that much.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for taking time to detail out your thoughts. I agree to  - we need to implement a batching mechanism so that the data can be sent only when required or a certain size is reached. Digging further into the problem of the Battery with GRPC I found out that it was not a problem with grpc but the context of the data which was larger than the data packet itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is applicable in your problem, but my team has previously managed to handle 30GB a day using just the AWS IoT message upload over MQTT, hooked onto a Kinesis stream that was linked to lambdas. The messages were processed pretty much in real time and then eventually when we had too many consumers we introduced the Kinesis Fan-Out (it basically creates copy-stream to enhance the read throughput). You just need to have enough shards and be conscious of the sharding keys (so... this would probably be a unique sharding key per client)

Comment: Hi @Kamil, we are currently doing the exact same way. now we want to take it out of AWS and run the setup locally.